# Randomizing return and doubling array size

Tags: java

I currently have this piece of code.

Currently what happens is that two arrays are being taken in, and all possible sequential combinations of the indices of Array A are being stored as a list of seperate arrays, each of which are the same size as array B. Currently to do this sizeA has to be smaller than sizeB.

```
import java.util.*;


public class Main {

public static void main(final String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    ArrayList<String> storeB= new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String> storeA = new ArrayList();

    Scanner scannerB = new Scanner(new File("fileB"));
    Scanner scannerA = new Scanner(new File("fileA"));

    while(scannerB.hasNext()) {
        String b = scannerB.next();{
            storeB.add(b);

        }           
    }



    while(scannerA.hasNext()) {
        String A = scannerA.next();{
            storeA.add(A);              

        }

    }           

    final int sizeA = storeA.size();
    final int sizeB = storeB.size();


    final List<int[]> combinations = getOrderings(sizeA-1, sizeB);


    for(final int[] combo : combinations) {

        for(final int value : combo) {
            System.out.print(value + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();

    }

}

private static List<int[]> getOrderings(final int maxIndex, final int size) {


    final List<int[]> result = new ArrayList<int[]>();

    if(maxIndex == 0) {
        final int[] array = new int[size];
        Arrays.fill(array, maxIndex);
        result.add(array);
        return result;
    }

        // creating an array for each occurence of maxIndex, and  generating each head 
        //recursively

    for(int i = 1; i < size - maxIndex + 1; ++i) {

        //Generating every possible head for the array
        final List<int[]> heads = getOrderings(maxIndex - 1, size - i);

        //Combining every head with the tail
        for(final int[] head : heads) {
            final int[] array = new int[size];
            System.arraycopy(head, 0, array, 0, head.length);

            //Filling the tail of the array with i maxIndex values
            for(int j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
                array[size - j] = maxIndex;
            result.add(array);
        }

    }

    return result;

}

}
```

I'm wondering, regardless  of sizeA and sizeB, how do I modify this to create arrays which are double sizeB and duplicate each index value. So if we had:
    [0,1,1,2] 
this would become:
    [0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2]
i.e duplicating each value and placing it next to it.

Also, how would I eliminate recursion in this so that rather than producing all possible combinations, on each call, a single array at random is produced rather than a list of arrays.

Thank you.

Comment: `getOrderings` doesn't make any sense to me. What does it have to do with the rest of this program?

Answer (score 1):

> So if we had: [0,1,1,2] this would become: [0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2] i.e duplicating each value and placing it next to it.

```
public int[] getArray(int originSize) {
    // Create a array double the size of originSize
    int[] result = new int[originSize * 2];

    // Iterate through 0 to originSize - 1 (This are your indicies)
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < originSize; ++i, j+=2)
    {
        // i is the index to insert into the new array.
        // j holds the current position in the new array.

        // On the first iteration i = 0 is written onto the 
        // position 0 and 1 in the new array
        // after that j is incremented by 2
        // to step over the written values.
        result[j] = i;
        result[j+1] = i;
    }   

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but  exactly will this work when sizeA is bigger than sizeB?

Comment: Please rephrase. If you only want to duplicate the indecies of one array why do you care for the size of another?

Comment: Sorry, I'm just having trouble seeing how this works in the context of the rest of the code, can you please show me how you ran it together?

Comment: Do you have any ideas on randomizing the return so that rather than all of the combinations being caluclated a random one is calculated and returned?

Comment: I don't understand, do you want random values instead of the indicies?

Comment: No, basically what the code does is it has two arrays and it puts all possible sequential combinations of the indices of one array, into a list of new arrays which are each of the size of the second array. Rather than calculating all possible combinations I want it to calculate and return a sequential combination at random.

Comment: Please edit your first post, maybe visualize what you want to achive then maybe someone will be able to help you.

Comment: I've just edited it, I don't know if this has made it clearer or not

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] sizeB_double = new int[sizeB.length()*2];

for(int i = 0; i<sizeB_double; i+=2)
{
   sizeB_double[i] = sizeB[i/2];
   if(sizeB_double.length > (i+1))
       sizeB_double[i+1] = sizeB[i/2];
}
```